# Disallow console to print any keys and take only arrows as input

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have the following code in a Console Application C#. The problem is if I give any input from keyboard other than Arrows, it prints those characters onto the console. Is there a way to prevent characters other than arrows to be printed on the Console. Also is there a way to enhance the following program.

```
class Program
{
    static ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
    // public ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            say();
        }
        while(keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow 
                || keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow 
                || keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow 
                || keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow);
    }

    public static void say()
    {
        if(keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Down");
        }
        else if(keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Up");
        }
        else if(keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right");
        }
        else if(keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Left");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your `Console.ReadKey();` and `Console.ReadKey(false);` both to `Console.ReadKey(true);`. I haven't tested this, but the [msdn-docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx) state: _"Determines whether to display the pressed key in the console window. true to not display the pressed key; otherwise, false."_, so I'm assuming it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter the output to the standart output stream.

The console uses a text writer to output the data coming from the standard input, and this text writer is invoked BEFORE the console gives you the key by `Console.ReadKey()`, therefore, you cannot cancel the outputting of the characters pressed. BUT!

You can set a custom text writer by `Console.SetOut();`

The code below sets a text writer which will filter everything. Only the Write(char) method is overridden and it is sufficient as far as I can see, if not, you can implement others.

When you need to actually write to the console, swap the text writer to a default one having standart output stream as the base stream, and voila:

```
class ConsoleFilteredOutput : TextWriter
    {
        public override void Write(char value)
        {

        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.Unicode; }
        }
    }

    static TextWriter standardOutputWriter = Console.Out;
    static ConsoleFilteredOutput filteredOutputWriter = new ConsoleFilteredOutput();

    static void WriteUnfiltered(string text)
    {
        Console.SetOut(standardOutputWriter);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.SetOut(filteredOutputWriter);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetOut(filteredOutputWriter);

        do
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            switch (keyinfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    WriteUnfiltered(keyinfo.Key.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Did you try ReadKey(true)? I think that should also work, but this is anyway something that we may need some other time

Comment: Yea ReadKey(true) works but when I give a non arrow character it simply exits the application

Comment: Ok. I think what is more important with these answers is not whether they are the best or not, but the new information and ways of programming we get out of them. Take care